# How do I access object attributes within a underscore each block

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I have a constructor which initialises 3 attributes with this.

I then have another method which loops over this.actors and performs some manipulation using the other two attributes. But with in the _.each block non of these attributes are accessible.

To simplify this.actors, this.mainPoint and this.actorsDistance are un defined within the _.each block.

```
function FindNearestPoint(actors, mainPoint) {
  //Assign the mainPoints co-ord to mainPoint
  this.mainPoint = actors[mainPoint];

  this.actors = actors;

  this.actorsDistance = {};
}

FindNearestPoint.prototype.getActorsDistance = function () {
  var i = 0;

  _.each(this.actors, function(el,key,list){
    this.actorsDistance[_.keys(this.actors)[i]] = Math.abs( 
      ( this.actors[key][0] - this.mainPoint[0] ) + 
      ( this.actors[key][1] - this.mainPoint[1] ) 
    );
    i++
  });
  return this.actorsDistance;
};
```

Comment: How are you calling `getActorsDistance`?

Comment: On an instance of FindNearestPoint like this                                  nearestDelivery.getActorsDistance();

Comment: But I am trying to call is within the constructor now, and pass in the attributes that I want to reference :)

Comment: Sure you haven't forgotten two `Math.sqrt()`s?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the control reaches the iterator function to `_.each`, reference to `this` changes. That is why those variables are `undefined`. In order to prevent that from happening, store the reference to `this` in another variable and use that inside the iterator function, like this

```
FindNearestPoint.prototype.getActorsDistance = function() {
    var that = this;   // Make `that` refer the current `this`
    _.each(this.actors, function(el, key, list) {
        that.actorsDistance[el] = Math.abs(
            (that.actors[key][0] - that.mainPoint[0]) +
            (that.actors[key][1] - that.mainPoint[1])
        );
    });
    return this.actorsDistance;
};
```

The other way to fix this would be to set the context while invoking `_.each`, like this

```
FindNearestPoint.prototype.getActorsDistance = function() {
    _.each(this.actors, function(el, key, list) {
        this.actorsDistance[el] = Math.abs(
            (this.actors[key][0] - this.mainPoint[0]) +
            (this.actors[key][1] - this.mainPoint[1])
        );
    }, this);            // Setting the current context to `this`
    return this.actorsDistance;
};
```

Comment: thefoureye you the man! Thanks, thinking about it now its common sense! :)

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the fact that `this` keyword inside your `each` loop refers to `this.actors` itself. The third argument of `_.each()`, however, is a **context** argument, so just use that. I.e.:

```
_.each(this.actors, function(el,key,list){
    this.actorsDistance[_.keys(list)[i]] = Math.abs( 
      ( list[key][0] - this.mainPoint[0] ) + 
      ( list[key][1] - this.mainPoint[1] ) 
    );
    i++
}, this);
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> _.each(this.actors, function(el,key,list){
> //                           ^^^^^^^^^^^
> ```

That should be clear enough actually. Don't use `this.actors[key]`, but just `el` - also because [`this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) inside the callback function is not the same as outside.

You will have the same issue with `this.mainPoint`, but you should cache those in separate variables anyway. If you don't want, you can pass `this` as the callback context as the third argument to [`_.each`](http://underscorejs.org/#each) like @thefoureye demonstrated.

Instead of mutating `this.actorsDistance`, you might as well return a new object:

```
FindNearestPoint.prototype.getActorsDistance = function() {
    var mainX = this.mainPoint[0],
        mainY = this.mainPoint[1];
    return _.reduce(this.actors, function(m, el, key){
        m[key] = Math.abs( el[0] - mainX  +  el[1] - mainY );
        return m;
    });
};
```